# Swift Set Comprehension Syntax

Tags: swift

```
var s = Set<NSDate>()
for z in y {
   s.insert(z)
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to write this in Swift? I tried to look for a Set comprehension syntax like in Python but couldn't find one.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `z` here is an array (or similar), you can just write `let s = Set(z)`.

This works because the Set type has an initializer [`init<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Element>(_: S)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Set_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structctr/Set/s:FVs3SetcuRd__s12SequenceTypexzWd__9Generator7Element_rFqd__GS_x_) which accepts any sequence, and creates a set by `insert()`ing each item from that sequence. You can see its implementation [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/87115f8729da41eb080bb99f4f266250a94cf0e3/stdlib/public/core/HashedCollections.swift.gyb#L750-L769).